# Locking subdomain document root folder name (cpanel)

Tags: domains, cpanel, document-root

I have moved the document root on one of my domains to serve content from RAM and as a result, the Time to First Byte on average dropped 10ms when I tested my server from the other end of North America.

In order for me to do this, I had to manually enter the shell and navigate to /var/cpanel/userdata/(username)/(domain) and find my domain and edit a couple of lines.

I basically followed instructions here: http://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/website/file-management/changing-the-document-root-with-root-access

I then saved the file and attempted to lock it by assigning file permissions 400 to the domain file instead of file permissions 755. I'm not sure if this will be sufficient to prevent the domain from being changed.

I went in cpanel after to check the document root folders for my domain and the document root that shows up is the old one (before I made the manual changes described above).

So my question is, how can I ensure that if someone (who is authorized) goes into the cpanel control panel that the document root folder can't be changed at all for any sub-domain I want?

Comment: You should be blogging some of this stuff. Clearly you are digging in deep and can offer some serious and valuable experience besides here. You probably will make Adsense revenue a bit easier on the blog. Cheers!!

Comment: It's a bit unclear to me exactly what you are asking to do. If you make the file too restrictive, then it might mean cPanel can't read it. The userdata file is 644 by default, and it's already owned by root, so only root can edit it already. Were you trying to prevent some other root level tool from changing it?